# How to update a shared layers used multiple times in the same network in Keras

Tags: keras

I am trying to implement a network found in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.03440.pdf; using a recurrent architecture using shared layers used several times in the same network. The problem is how to implement the update of these layers by the mean of the gradients computed for each forward pass through each of these layers.

I am using tensorflow backend and I did not find how the gradients are computed for this kind of shared weights.

I only found that the gradients function only return 1 set of gradients by layer and not one by forward pass of this layer. So I do not know if the returned gradients are aggregated from the multiple gradients or if one of them is simply returned.

To only other way to solve my problem I can think of is to not use shared weights and use a custom optimizer to get the mean gradients by group of affiliated layers, but it would be much less optimized.

Comment: Do you want to update weights manually? Are you creating a new type of layer? -- Normally keras does everything automatically for you....

Comment: Yes I want to choose how to update the weights of my layer and update them once not for each iteration of the recursive loop.